# How to save the value of multiple checkboxes in a single column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called profiles, and in which I have several columns: address, phone, languages. I would like to be able to save in the languages ​​column, several languages ​​for example: English, German, Spanish and to be able to access each language separately from the profiles / show view. In the profiles / new view, I would select the languages ​​using the checkbox. what I can't do is in the controller in the parameters like saving in the database
my view:

```
<div class="col-xl-8">
  <h4>Idiomas:</h4>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :es, class:'form-check-input' %>
    <%= f.label :es, "Español" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :en, class:'form-check-input' %>
    <%= f.label :en, "Inglés" %>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :pt, class:'form-check-input' %>
    <%= f.label :pt, "Portugués" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :fr, class:'form-check-input' %>
    <%= f.label :fr, "Francés" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :it, class:'form-check-input' %>
    <%= f.label :it, "Italiano" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :ge, class:'form-check-input' %>
    <%= f.label :ge, "Alemán" %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing several languages in the same column is a violation of database normalization.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

For instance, it's very difficult to query people who speak `english`, if you want to add/change a language you have to touch almost all rows etc etc.

I think what you should do is split the language information from the profile table and use a profiles_languages table to connect the both.

### profiles table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | karlita94 |
| 2 | peter |

### languages table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | english |
| 2 | spanish |

### profiles_languages table

| id | profile_id | language_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) to hold a sequence of bits which represent your choice languages as a single column in database, there's some gems support `bit field`(https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Bit_Fields).

demo with [flag_shih_tzu](https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu) gem

```
# migration
 add_column :profiles, :flags, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0
 # flag_shih_tzu-managed bit field
 # Effective booleans which will be stored on the flags column:
 # t.boolean      :en
 # t.boolean      :es
 # t.boolean      :fr
 # and so on ...

# models/profile.rb
class Profile
 include FlagShihTzu
 has_flags 1 => :en,
           2 => :es,
           3 => :fr
end

profile = Profile.new
profile.en = true
profile.es = true
profile.save

profile = Profile.last
profile.en? # true
profile.es? # true
profile.fr? # false
```

so you could set `true` for selected languages from your view checked check-boxes.

**update**
in case you don't want to use those `bitfield` gems above, here is demo with [postgres bitstring](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_postgresql.html#bit-string-types) (or [mysql binary-varbinary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)), so your languages setting be cached on database as bit sequence like this "01010011", 1: selected, 0: none.

```rb
create_table :profiles, force: true do |t|
  t.column :languages, "bit(8)" # "bit(16)" whatever ...
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
 before_create :set_default_languages
 
 # you could refactor as you want
 [:ruby, :python, :js, :java, ...].each_with_index do |lang, index|
    define_method("#{lang}?") do
      result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
      "Select get_bit(languages, #{index}) 
        From profiles Where id = #{self.id} Limit 1")

      result&.first.values&.first == 1
    end

    define_method("#{lang}!") do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
      "Update profiles SET languages = 
        set_bit(languages, #{index}, 1) Where id = #{self.id}")
    end
  end

 private
 
  def set_default_languages
    self.languages = "00000000"
  end
end

profile = Profile.create(...)
profile.ruby? # false
profile.ruby! # set to 1
profile.reload
profile.ruby? # true
```

Comment: My idea is to save each of the checkbox values ​​in a single column and not each checkbox value in a separate column. I don't know if it can be saved as an array

Comment: `bitfield` (and also `bitstring`) is an array of bits `0101010`, each bit (0 or 1) represent for each checkbox value (selected or not), and you could get it's actually value (:en or, :es, ...) by the index of it on the bits array. @karlita94

Comment: you could image `bitfield` like array of langues `:en :es :fr :de :it ...`, and it's just a single column on data table, if the column value is `11000...` that mean you selected `:en` and `:es`. @karlita94

Comment: my idea was to use checkbox_tag and collect the data as an array and save it in a single column. I don't know if you can do that.

Comment: @karlita94 as i said, each checkbox value corresponding to an index in the bits array, so you collect checkbox values from parameters then map to bits array then save to a bits-field column.